# Getting a specific version of a Form via Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: winforms, tfs

I am developing a WinForms C# projet within my company.
We use Visual Studio 2010 and Team Foundation Server 2010 to manage code versions.

I want to restore a version of a Form.
Let's call the Form MyForm.
MyForm is made up of three files :

- MyForm.cs which contains the code behind.
- MyForm.Designer.cs which contains code automatically generated by VS2010 when designing the Form.
- MyForm.resx.

Here is a simplified historic of change sets :

- Change set number : 1587. Files archived :

  - MyForm.Designer.cs. A TextBox control has been added. Let's call the TextBox control txtMyBox.
  - MyForm.cs. txtMyBox is used in the code behind.
- Change set number : 1390. Files archived :

  - MyForm.cs
- Change set number : 1299. Files archived :

  - MyForm.cs
  - MyForm.Designer.cs
- ...
- Change set number : 986. Files archived :

  - MyForm.cs
  - MyForm.Designer.cs
  - MyForm.resx

Here is the procedure I have followed :

1. Right-clicking the MyForm.cs file in the solution explorer.
2. Clicking the "Getting a specific version" option in the contextual menu.
3. Selecting the change set number 1390 and then clicking the "Getting" button.

Then I have tried to open MyForm in the designer but an error has been displayed.
The error message has told me that the extraction has been cancelled.

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

you have the old version of MyForm.cs (no textBox) but the latest version of MyForm.Designer.cs (with TextBox).

You can do a couple of things

1. Do a get specific version on the folder containing both files, this will revert all files to the version available when changeset 1390 was checked in. (you might not want to do this if you have other files that you need to have the latest version of)
2. Do a get specific version on MyForm.cs at 1390 and a get specific version on MyForm.Designer.cs at 1299

This should ensure that both files are in sync with one another and fix the problem.

Comment: I have tried the option 2 but without success. I am still getting an error message. I can not do the option 1 because the 3 files of MyForm are contained in a folder with other Form files - Each Form is made up of 3 files as MyForm.

Comment: Is it actually getting anything, TFS can be funny like that. Do a diff between the changeset and the local file system. You might want to hit the 2 checkboxes at the bottom of the get dialogue "Overwrite of writable files that are not checked out" and "Overwrite all files even if the local version matched the specified version"

Comment: I have done a get specific version on MyForm.cs at 1390 and on MyForm.Designer.cs at 1299. Then I have compared my local versions of MyForm.cs and MyForm.Designer.cs against their respective server last versions. Local versions and server versions are not the same and that's ok. But MyForm.cs and MyForm.Designer.cs are not extracted after a get specific version. When I try to open MyForm in the designer mode then the server last versions of MyForm.cs and MyForm.Designer.cs are automatically extracted. And then an error message is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of old but I had this same issue recently and this is my fix. VS2012 and TFS2012

Delete the local workspace version and then get latest. Thats it.